# trouble publishing an bulk Sms app in play store

Tags: android, sms, google-play-services, google-play-console

I have developed an android app called "Bulk Sms sender", The main idea of this app is to create groups and send messages to multiple recipients with a single tap. This requires Send.Sms permission. here's what the rejection mail says:

> Apps must be actively registered as the default SMS, Phone, or Assistant handler before prompting users to accept any SMS or Call Log permissions. Those apps must immediately stop using the permission when they’re no longer the default handler.
> You declared default SMS handling in your declaration form, but your app isn’t the registered default handler for SMS or its other core functionality.

Note: This app does not contain all the screens that a default SMS app contains like chatting layout, blocking features, adding new contact, etc. If this is the problems please suggest me a solution so that I don't have to design a whole new SMS app.

Thanks in Advance.

I have tried submitting an appeal explaining why I need this permission but still got rejected.
So after getting rejected many times I thought making my app default would solve the problem.
Just like the default SMS app, this app does not work if the user doesn't make it the default SMS app. But it still got rejected :)